# how to change scrolable div height?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. At first I has a this view of page:
[image]
after I changed the post editor, its height became bigger, and after page reload some messages become hidden until you scroll it to the end. (post editor was fixed to bottom and i don't change this)
[image]
when I try to change height or padding, its not work as I want and I don't see height parameter on styles.

here is html:

```
<!-- container with list of messages and text editor -->
<div class="o_ThreadView_core d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">

  <!-- messages list -->
  <div id="MessageList" class="o_MessageList o_ThreadView_messageList">
    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
    <div class="o_MessageList_separator o_MessageList_separatorDate o_MessageList_item pt-4">
      <hr class="o_MessageList_separatorLine">
      <span class="o_MessageList_separatorLabel o_MessageList_separatorLabelDate">28 червня 2022 р.</span>
      <hr class="o_MessageList_separatorLine">
    </div>
  
    ...
    <div role="group" aria-label="Повідомлення" data-message-local-id="mail.message(id: 858)" class="o_Message position-relative pt-1 o-discussion o-squashed o_MessageList_item o_MessageList_message">
      <div class="d-flex flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="o_Message_highlightIndicator"></div>
        <div class="o_Message_sidebar o-message-squashed align-items-start"></div>
        <div class="o_Message_core flex-grow-1">
          <div class="o_Message_content mx-2">
            <div class="o_Message_prettyBody">
              <p>jf;fj;</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- text editor -->
  <div class="o_Composer o-has-current-partner-avatar o-has-footer o-is-compact o_ThreadView_composer">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and all active css styles:

```
.container {
    min-width: 0;
    flex-grow: 1 !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    display: flex !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

.message_container {
    padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    direction: ltr;
}

.text_editor {
    padding-top: 1.5rem;
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1.5rem 0.25rem;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "sidebar-header core-header" "sidebar-main core-main" "sidebar-footer core-footer";
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;direction: ltr;
}
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok i got it. I found a child of the input field element that I was able to pass a parameter to directly. It turns out that my framework scrolls the element to the end, but the input field is initialized after that, so the position shifts.

Comment: I would have solved that yesterday if your question was a bit more clear. I thought your problem was the scrollbar going up and not the container shifting upwards.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume what you want to do is scroll to the bottom every time the div gets automatically to the top. To do that:

```
var list = document.querySelector(); //The list of the messages
function toBottom(element=list){
    element.scrollTo(0, element.scrollHeight); //Scroll to bottom
}
```

Then, run `toBottom(list)` every time you believe that it gets scrolled up.
(Edit: For example, you could do so every time you load a new message or open the post editor (?), which is when it all probably happens)

If there is something that I didn't get about your question, please let me know so I can edit this.